# Reactively reacting to Map-updated

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, reactive, flux

I have an application based on Java and Spring (Springboot, Spring-reactive, Spring-Kafka) witch continuously consumes information from a Kafka-topic and store the data with a key in a ConcurrentHashMap (via a simple wrapper). The application also contains an REST-API for fetching streaming information using Reactive Flux.

I would like to come up with a way of where it is possible to call the API for data from the map (using a key), where the response is a stream of the currently associated value from the map together with subsequent changes to the value (as updated from the topic) i.e without closing the stream.

It feels like this should be possible using maby a `PropertyChangeListener` combined with a `Flux.Generate` but my reactive skills are to weak to see how I should achieve this. Ive done some tries but I cant see how to get the `Generator` to emit on `PropertyChangeEvents`.

Would this be possible?
If anyone could provide me with a example for this, or maby point me to one online it would be much appreciated.

BR

Comment: This is what KTables are for. Why do you need to use a ConcurrentHashMap? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: To be honest - no particular reason at all. The Map is updated by a number of threads, as I understand Spring-Kafka, and read by another which made me assume I would need some kind of thread-safety. However this was just a first approach and not thought through I admit. Ill take a look at KTable which Ive never looked at previously.

Comment: Regarding Spring (old blog, but should get the point across). https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/09/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-6-state-stores-and-interactive-queries